# How to delete a specific item from AsyncStorage in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to delete a specific post, but when i click in the button nothing happens, i don't know what i missing

**Function**

```
removePost = async (post_id) => {
try {

    const posts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('posts');
    let postsFav = JSON.parse(postsJSON);
    postsItems = postsFav.filter(function(e){ return e.post_id == post_id })
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('posts', postsItems);

} catch(error) {

}};
```

**Button**

```
<Button onPress={this.removePost.bind(this, item.post_id)}>
```

Comment: I guess, `JSON.parse(postsJSON);` should be `JSON.parse(posts);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncStorage.setItem()` to update `posts` with the `postItems`.

```js
removePost = async (post_id) => {
try {
  const posts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('posts');
  let postsFav = JSON.parse(posts);
  const postsItems = postsFav.filter(function(e){ return e.post_id !== post_id });

  // updating 'posts' with the updated 'postsItems'
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(postsItems));

} catch(error) {
  console.log('error: ', error);
}};
```

Comment: Did you try with `JSON.parse(posts);`? maybe typo.

Comment: it works on the reverse side, leaves the one I want to eliminate and removes the rest

Comment: Should be `return e.post_id !== post_id` instead of `return e.post_id == post_id`?

Comment: When i delete the post, i need to refresh the page, so that it disappears, is something to be added in the function?

Comment: You can save the `posts` in a static variable like `this.state.posts = await AsyncStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(postsItems)); ` then when the state is changed the render method will be called * re-render the View.

Comment: mmm  i test it but not work, i think is because i have a conflict, already i have a function to fetch the posts or what?

Comment: this is the function to fetch posts:   async fetch () {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      uid = user.uid;

      let postsJSON= await AsyncStorage.getItem('posts');
      let postsFav = JSON.parse(postsJSON);
      postsItems = postsFav.filter(function(e){
            return e.userId == uid
        })
      const postsArray = postsItems || [];
      this.setState({
        posts: postsArray
      });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170651/discussion-between-sajib-khan-and-bdroid).

Answer (score 0):

key_name from remove and item which you want to remove:-

AsyncStorage.removeItem('key_name', Items);

Answer (score -1):

Here what you have to do delete the item from the array and then save it to local-storage

```
 removePost = async (post_id) => {
 try {
  const posts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('posts');
  let postsFav = JSON.parse(postsJSON);
  postsItems = postsFav.filter(function(e){ return e.post_id == post_id 
 })

 var index = array.indexOf(postsItems); // we are finding index of array 
 we want to remove form store array in AsyncStorage .  
  if (index > -1) {
   postsFav.splice(index, 1); //
  }
  AsyncStorage.setItem('post',postsFav); // saving remains array in local storage

} catch(error) {

}};
```

Then save the array in AsyncStorage, 
Hope this will help you, Let me any know if you have question 
Thanks

Comment: I'm using react native,  you can create a full example please

Comment: hey buddy have created example